# Function that returns a pointer to a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have a linked list node class

```
class node {
    private: 
        node *next_node;
    public:
        node *next() const;
};

node *node::next() const {
    return next_node;
}
```

Does next() return a node **next_node or node *next_node. Also what is the significance of either in implementing the list class functions (ie. insert, remove, find)?

The reason I would think it returns a **next_node is because next_node is already a pointer and returning it in a function as a pointer would make it a pointer to a pointer. I read in other questions such as: [Linked list head double pointer passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313233/linked-list-head-double-pointer-passing) that double pointers also work in list operations so I was a bit confused.

Comment: I suggest that you do your homework yourself

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, why you think this might return a `node**`?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been in school for a couple months. I wanted to brush up on programming skills and pointers is one of my weak points. I understand if this question can come off as a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `node::next()` function as implemented is returning a copy of the `next_node` member variable.  Both `next_node` and this copy point to the same `node` instance but they are otherwise independent of each other.

Here is some rather bad ASCII art that tries to demonstrate their relationship

```
next_node ----> [node instance]
                ^
the copy ------/
```

Comment: What would be the difference if the function was implemented as

    node node::next() const {
        return next_node;
    }

Would this just simply return the next_node by value and be the same as: 

    node *node::next() const {
        return &next_node;
   }

Comment: @rcell that actually won't compile. You need to write `node node::next() const { return *next_node; }`.  This would return a shallow copy of the `next_node` value.

Comment: I would've thought that `return *next_node;` would have been the same as `*node::next`. By my understanding then the latter is return what is called a deep copy?

Answer (score 0):

As the declaration says, it returns a pointer to the next node, of type `node*`.

It's used to advance through the list; for example:

```
for (node * n = list.head(); n; n = n->next()) {
    // Process node n
}
```